# Resque error: DirtyExit - Child process received unhandled signal

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, redis, resque, amazon-elasticache

My background jobs are all failing with the following error Resque::DirtyExit Child process received unhandled signal. After I restart the server they work for some minutes and then start failing. If I run the single jobs from Resque-schedule, they work fine.

Below is a part of the output of the resque-pool.stderr.log:

I've tried reducing the number of jobs to only one that only logs to a file, but the error persists. 
I've also tried rebuilding the AWS server instance and the redis instance but the error is still there.

System details: 
- Server instance: AWS linux version ( 4.14.88-72.76.amzn1.x86_64)
- Resque version: 1.27.4
- Redis: AWS elastic cache
- ruby: 2.3.8
- rails: 4.2

```
* Process memory map:

5613e7788000-5613e7a77000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 170946                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/bin/ruby
5613e7c76000-5613e7c7c000 rw-p 002ee000 ca:01 170946                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/bin/ruby
5613e7c7c000-5613e7c8e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
5613e7e33000-5613e95ce000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
5613e95ce000-5613f2de3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
5613f2de3000-5613f314a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
5613f314a000-5613f316b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7faccc000000-7faccc021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7faccc021000-7facd0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facd0000000-7facd0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facd0021000-7facd4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facd4000000-7facd4021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facd4021000-7facd8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facd8000000-7facd8021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facd8021000-7facdc000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facdc000000-7facdc13c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facdc13c000-7face0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7face4000000-7face4021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7face4021000-7face421b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7face421b000-7face4222000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7face4222000-7face8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7faceb144000-7facec000000 r--s 00000000 ca:01 170946                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/bin/ruby
7facec000000-7facec021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facec021000-7facec508000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facec508000-7facf0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facf0890000-7facf0aa3000 r--s 00000000 ca:01 262174                     /lib64/libc-2.17.so
7facf0aa3000-7facf0d4c000 r--s 00000000 ca:01 929288                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/grpc-1.14.2-x86_64-linux/src/ruby/lib/grpc/2.3/grpc_c.so
7facf0d4c000-7facf1150000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facf1150000-7facf1151000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171207                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/thread.so
7facf1151000-7facf1350000 ---p 00001000 ca:01 171207                     
7facf1552000-7facf1553000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facf1553000-7facf1d53000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facf1d53000-7facf1d54000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/bootsnap.so
7facf3067000-7facf3266000 ---p 00003000 ca:01 917677                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/bootsnap.so
7facf3266000-7facf3267000 rw-p 00002000 ca:01 917677                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/bootsnap.so
7facf32fd000-7facf3310000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 917623                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.4/lib/msgpack/msgpack.so
7facf3310000-7facf3510000 ---p 00013000 ca:01 917623                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.4/lib/msgpack/msgpack.so
7facf3510000-7facf3511000 rw-p 00013000 ca:01 917623                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.4/lib/msgpack/msgpack.so
7facf3511000-7facf3515000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171126                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/io/console.so
7facf3515000-7facf3715000 ---p 00004000 ca:01 171126                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/io/console.so
7facf3715000-7facf3716000 rw-p 00004000 ca:01 171126                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/io/console.so
7facf3716000-7facf376d000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 929163                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/google-protobuf-3.6.1-x86_64-linux/lib/google/2.3/protobuf_c.so
7facf376d000-7facf396c000 ---p 00057000 ca:01 929163                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/google-protobuf-3.6.1-x86_64-linux/lib/google/2.3/protobuf_c.so
7facf396c000-7facf3974000 r--p 00056000 ca:01 929163                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/google-protobuf-3.6.1-x86_64-linux/lib/google/2.3/protobuf_c.so
7facf3974000-7facf3976000 rw-p 0005e000 ca:01 929163                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/google-protobuf-3.6.1-x86_64-linux/lib/google/2.3/protobuf_c.so
7facf3976000-7facf3bdd000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 929288                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/grpc-1.14.2-x86_64-linux/src/ruby/lib/grpc/2.3/grpc_c.so
7facf3bdd000-7facf3ddd000 ---p 00267000 ca:01 929288                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/grpc-1.14.2-x86_64-linux/src/ruby/lib/grpc/2.3/grpc_c.so
7facf3ddd000-7facf3df2000 r--p 00267000 ca:01 929288                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/grpc-1.14.2-x86_64-linux/src/ruby/lib/grpc/2.3/grpc_c.so
7facf3df2000-7facf3df9000 rw-p 0027c000 ca:01 929288                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/grpc-1.14.2-x86_64-linux/src/ruby/lib/grpc/2.3/grpc_c.so
7facf3df9000-7facf3dfe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facf3dfe000-7facf3e00000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 804772                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.3/lib/debug_inspector.so
7facf3e00000-7facf3fff000 ---p 00002000 ca:01 804772                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.3/lib/debug_inspector.so
7facf3fff000-7facf4000000 rw-p 00001000 ca:01 804772                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.3/lib/debug_inspector.so
7facf4000000-7facf4054000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facf4054000-7facf8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facf800c000-7facf810d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facf810d000-7facf8110000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 929639                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/google-cloud-debugger-0.32.2/lib/google/cloud/debugger/debugger_c.so
7facf8110000-7facf8310000 ---p 00003000 ca:01 929639                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/google-cloud-debugger-0.32.2/lib/google/cloud/debugger/debugger_c.so
7facf8310000-7facf8311000 rw-p 00003000 ca:01 929639                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/google-cloud-debugger-0.32.2/lib/google/cloud/debugger/debugger_c.so
7facf8311000-7facf8313000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171173                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/iso_8859_1.so
7facf8313000-7facf8512000 ---p 00002000 ca:01 171173                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/iso_8859_1.so
7facf8512000-7facf8513000 rw-p 00001000 ca:01 171173                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/iso_8859_1.so
7facf8513000-7facf851e000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171211                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/objspace.so
7facf851e000-7facf871e000 ---p 0000b000 ca:01 171211                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/objspace.so
7facf871e000-7facf871f000 rw-p 0000b000 ca:01 171211                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/objspace.so
7facf871f000-7facf8722000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171138                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/windows_31j.so
7facf8722000-7facf8921000 ---p 00003000 ca:01 171138                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/windows_31j.so
7facf8921000-7facf8922000 rw-p 00002000 ca:01 171138                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/windows_31j.so
7facf8922000-7facf8f43000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 1053096                    /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/lib/v8/init.so
7facf8f43000-7facf9143000 ---p 00621000 ca:01 1053096                    /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/lib/v8/init.so
7facf9143000-7facf917e000 rw-p 00621000 ca:01 1053096                    /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.3/lib/v8/init.so
7facf917e000-7facf9182000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facf9182000-7facf918c000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171123                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/json/ext/generator.so
7facf918c000-7facf938b000 ---p 0000a000 ca:01 171123                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/json/ext/generator.so
7facf938b000-7facf938c000 rw-p 00009000 ca:01 171123                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/json/ext/generator.so
7facf938c000-7facf9392000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171124                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/json/ext/parser.so
7facf9392000-7facf9591000 ---p 00006000 ca:01 171124                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/json/ext/parser.so
7facf9591000-7facf9592000 rw-p 00005000 ca:01 171124                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/json/ext/parser.so
7facf9592000-7facf9595000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171157                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/utf_16_32.so
7facf9595000-7facf9795000 ---p 00003000 ca:01 171157                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/utf_16_32.so
7facf9795000-7facf9796000 rw-p 00003000 ca:01 171157                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/utf_16_32.so
7facf9796000-7facf97a2000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 262192                     /lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
7facf97a2000-7facf99a1000 ---p 0000c000 ca:01 262192                     /lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
7facf99a1000-7facf99a2000 r--p 0000b000 ca:01 262192                     /lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
7facf99a2000-7facf99a3000 rw-p 0000c000 ca:01 262192                     /lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
7facf99a3000-7facf99a9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facf99a9000-7facf99aa000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facf99aa000-7facfa1aa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facfa1aa000-7facfa1c0000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 262163                     /lib64/libgcc_s-7-20170915.so.1
7facfa1c0000-7facfa3bf000 ---p 00016000 ca:01 262163                     /lib64/libgcc_s-7-20170915.so.1
7facfa3bf000-7facfa3c0000 rw-p 00015000 ca:01 262163                     /lib64/libgcc_s-7-20170915.so.1
7facfa3c0000-7facfa535000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 3438                       /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.24
7facfa535000-7facfa735000 ---p 00175000 ca:01 3438                       /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.24
7facfa735000-7facfa73f000 r--p 00175000 ca:01 3438                       /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.24
7facfa73f000-7facfa741000 rw-p 0017f000 ca:01 3438                       /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.24
7facfa741000-7facfa745000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facfa745000-7facfa99d000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 145026                     /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
7facfa99d000-7facfab9c000 ---p 00258000 ca:01 145026                     /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
7facfab9c000-7facfac1d000 rw-p 00257000 ca:01 145026                     /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
7facfac1d000-7facfac22000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facfac22000-7facfac32000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 931802                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
7facfac32000-7facfae32000 ---p 00010000 ca:01 931802                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
7facfae32000-7facfae34000 rw-p 00010000 ca:01 931802                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
7facfae34000-7facfae4b000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 3014                       /usr/lib64/gconv/CP932.so
7facfae4b000-7facfb04a000 ---p 00017000 ca:01 3014                       /usr/lib64/gconv/CP932.so
7facfb04a000-7facfb04b000 r--p 00016000 ca:01 3014                       /usr/lib64/gconv/CP932.so
7facfb04b000-7facfb04c000 rw-p 00017000 ca:01 3014                       /usr/lib64/gconv/CP932.so
7facfb04c000-7facfb050000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 433559                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/racc/cparse.so
7facfb050000-7facfb24f000 ---p 00004000 ca:01 433559                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/racc/cparse.so
7facfb24f000-7facfb250000 rw-p 00003000 ca:01 433559                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/racc/cparse.so
7facfb250000-7facfb273000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 3441                       /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5.0.99
7facfb273000-7facfb473000 ---p 00023000 ca:01 3441                       /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5.0.99
7facfb473000-7facfb474000 rw-p 00023000 ca:01 3441                       /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5.0.99
7facfb474000-7facfb695000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 800452                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.5/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
7facfb695000-7facfb895000 ---p 00221000 ca:01 800452                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.5/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
7facfb895000-7facfb8a1000 rw-p 00221000 ca:01 800452                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.5/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
7facfb8a1000-7facfb8a3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facfb8a3000-7facfb8a4000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171133                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/digest/sha2.so
7facfb8a4000-7facfbaa4000 ---p 00001000 ca:01 171133                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/digest/sha2.so
7facfbaa4000-7facfbaa5000 rw-p 00001000 ca:01 171133                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/digest/sha2.so
7facfbaa5000-7facfbab9000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171196                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/bigdecimal.so
7facfbab9000-7facfbcb8000 ---p 00014000 ca:01 171196                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/bigdecimal.so
7facfbcb8000-7facfbcb9000 rw-p 00013000 ca:01 171196                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/bigdecimal.so
7facfbcb9000-7facfbcd8000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 4202                       /usr/lib64/libyaml-0.so.2.0.4
7facfbcd8000-7facfbed7000 ---p 0001f000 ca:01 4202                       /usr/lib64/libyaml-0.so.2.0.4
7facfbed7000-7facfbed8000 rw-p 0001e000 ca:01 4202                       /usr/lib64/libyaml-0.so.2.0.4
7facfbed8000-7facfbede000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171118                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/psych.so
7facfbede000-7facfc0de000 ---p 00006000 ca:01 171118                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/psych.so
7facfc0de000-7facfc0df000 rw-p 00006000 ca:01 171118                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/psych.so
7facfc0df000-7facfc0e0000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171122                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/fcntl.so
7facfc0e0000-7facfc2df000 ---p 00001000 ca:01 171122                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/fcntl.so
7facfc2df000-7facfc2e0000 rw-p 00000000 ca:01 171122                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/fcntl.so
7facfc2e0000-7facfc2e6000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171199                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/strscan.so
7facfc2e6000-7facfc4e6000 ---p 00006000 ca:01 171199                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/strscan.so
7facfc4e6000-7facfc4e7000 rw-p 00006000 ca:01 171199                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/strscan.so
7facfc4e7000-7facfc4e8000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171132                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/digest/md5.so
7facfc4e8000-7facfc6e7000 ---p 00001000 ca:01 171132                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/digest/md5.so
7facfc6e7000-7facfc6e8000 rw-p 00000000 ca:01 171132                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/digest/md5.so
7facfc6e8000-7facfc6f8000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171214                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/zlib.so
7facfc6f8000-7facfc8f7000 ---p 00010000 ca:01 171214                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/zlib.so
7facfc8f7000-7facfc8f8000 rw-p 0000f000 ca:01 171214                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/zlib.so
7facfc8f8000-7facfc92e000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171193                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/date_core.so
7facfc92e000-7facfcb2d000 ---p 00036000 ca:01 171193                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/date_core.so
7facfcb2d000-7facfcb2f000 rw-p 00035000 ca:01 171193                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/date_core.so
7facfcb2f000-7facfcb31000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facfcb31000-7facfcb3b000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 930573                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/ext/generator.so
7facfcb3b000-7facfcd3a000 ---p 0000a000 ca:01 930573                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/ext/generator.so
7facfcd3a000-7facfcd3b000 rw-p 00009000 ca:01 930573                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/ext/generator.so
7facfcd3b000-7facfcd3c000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171140                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/utf_32le.so
7facfcd3c000-7facfcf3c000 ---p 00001000 ca:01 171140                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/utf_32le.so
7facfcf3c000-7facfcf3d000 rw-p 00001000 ca:01 171140                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/utf_32le.so
7facfcf3d000-7facfcf3e000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171188                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/utf_32be.so
7facfcf3e000-7facfd13e000 ---p 00001000 ca:01 171188                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/utf_32be.so
7facfd13e000-7facfd13f000 rw-p 00001000 ca:01 171188                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/utf_32be.so
7facfd13f000-7facfd140000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171151                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/utf_16le.so
7facfd140000-7facfd340000 ---p 00001000 ca:01 171151                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/utf_16le.so
7facfd340000-7facfd341000 rw-p 00001000 ca:01 171151                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/utf_16le.so
7facfd341000-7facfd342000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171192                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/utf_16be.so
7facfd342000-7facfd542000 ---p 00001000 ca:01 171192                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/utf_16be.so
7facfd542000-7facfd543000 rw-p 00001000 ca:01 171192                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/utf_16be.so
7facfd543000-7facfd549000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 930581                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/ext/parser.so
7facfd549000-7facfd748000 ---p 00006000 ca:01 930581                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/ext/parser.so
7facfd748000-7facfd749000 rw-p 00005000 ca:01 930581                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/ext/parser.so
7facfd749000-7facfd74a000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171127                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/io/nonblock.so
7facfd74a000-7facfd94a000 ---p 00001000 ca:01 171127                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/io/nonblock.so
7facfd94a000-7facfd94b000 rw-p 00001000 ca:01 171127                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/io/nonblock.so
7facfd94b000-7facfd99d000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171134                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
7facfd99d000-7facfdb9d000 ---p 00052000 ca:01 171134                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
7facfdb9d000-7facfdba1000 rw-p 00052000 ca:01 171134                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
7facfdba1000-7facfdba2000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171125                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/io/wait.so
7facfdba2000-7facfdda2000 ---p 00001000 ca:01 171125                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/io/wait.so
7facfdda2000-7facfdda3000 rw-p 00001000 ca:01 171125                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/io/wait.so
7facfdda3000-7facfddcd000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171212                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/socket.so
7facfddcd000-7facfdfcd000 ---p 0002a000 ca:01 171212                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/socket.so
7facfdfcd000-7facfdfce000 rw-p 0002a000 ca:01 171212                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/socket.so
7facfdfce000-7facfdfeb000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 262220                     /lib64/libtinfo.so.5.7
7facfdfeb000-7facfe1ea000 ---p 0001d000 ca:01 262220                     /lib64/libtinfo.so.5.7
7facfe1ea000-7facfe1ef000 rw-p 0001c000 ca:01 262220                     /lib64/libtinfo.so.5.7
7facfe1ef000-7facfe214000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 262216                     /lib64/libncurses.so.5.7
7facfe214000-7facfe414000 ---p 00025000 ca:01 262216                     /lib64/libncurses.so.5.7
7facfe414000-7facfe415000 rw-p 00025000 ca:01 262216                     /lib64/libncurses.so.5.7
7facfe415000-7facfe451000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 262236                     /lib64/libreadline.so.6.2
7facfe451000-7facfe651000 ---p 0003c000 ca:01 262236                     /lib64/libreadline.so.6.2
7facfe651000-7facfe659000 rw-p 0003c000 ca:01 262236                     /lib64/libreadline.so.6.2
7facfe659000-7facfe65a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facfe65a000-7facfe661000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171128                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/readline.so
7facfe661000-7facfe861000 ---p 00007000 ca:01 171128                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/readline.so
7facfe861000-7facfe862000 rw-p 00007000 ca:01 171128                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/readline.so
7facfe862000-7facfe863000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 171204                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/cgi/escape.so
7facfe863000-7facfea63000 ---p 00001000 ca:01 171204                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/cgi/escape.so
7facfea63000-7facfea64000 rw-p 00001000 ca:01 171204                     /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/cgi/escape.so
7facfea64000-7facfea82000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 3344                       /usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1
7facfea82000-7facfec81000 ---p 0001e000 ca:01 3344                       /usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1
7facfec81000-7facfec82000 r--p 0001d000 ca:01 3344                       /usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1
7facfec82000-7facfec83000 rw-p 0001e000 ca:01 3344                       /usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1
7facfec83000-7facfec85000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facfec85000-7facfec9b000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 262202                     /lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
7facfec9b000-7facfee9a000 ---p 00016000 ca:01 262202                     /lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
7facfee9a000-7facfee9b000 r--p 00015000 ca:01 262202                     /lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
7facfee9b000-7facfee9c000 rw-p 00016000 ca:01 262202                     /lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
7facfee9c000-7facfee9e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7facfee9e000-7facfeea1000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 262262                     /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.5
7facfeea1000-7facff0a0000 ---p 00003000 ca:01 262262                     /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.5
7facff0a0000-7facff0a1000 rw-p 00002000 ca:01 262262                     /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.5
7facff0a1000-7facff0ae000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 7456                       /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7facff0ae000-7facff2ad000 ---p 0000d000 ca:01 7456                       /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7facff2ad000-7facff2ae000 r--p 0000c000 ca:01 7456                       /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7facff2ae000-7facff2af000 rw-p 0000d000 ca:01 7456                       /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7facff2af000-7facff2df000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 7448                       /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
7facff2df000-7facff4df000 ---p 00030000 ca:01 7448                       /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
7facff4df000-7facff4e1000 r--p 00030000 ca:01 7448                       /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
7facff4e1000-7facff4e2000 rw-p 00032000 ca:01 7448                       /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
7facff4e2000-7facff4e5000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 3357                       /usr/lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
7facff4e5000-7facff6e4000 ---p 00003000 ca:01 3357                       /usr/lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
7facff6e4000-7facff6e5000 rw-p 00002000 ca:01 3357                       /usr/lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
7facff6e5000-7facff7bd000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 7454                       /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
7facff7bd000-7facff9bc000 ---p 000d8000 ca:01 7454                       /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
7facff9bc000-7facff9ca000 r--p 000d7000 ca:01 7454                       /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
7facff9ca000-7facff9cd000 rw-p 000e5000 ca:01 7454                       /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
7facff9cd000-7facffa17000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 7444                       


[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

E0910 10:33:49.859056505   26018 sync_posix.cc:47]           assertion failed: pthread_mutex_lock(mu) == 0
E0910 10:33:55.198436313   26035 sync_posix.cc:47]           assertion failed: pthread_mutex_lock(mu) == 0
E0910 10:34:00.233557356   26046 sync_posix.cc:47]           assertion failed: pthread_mutex_lock(mu) == 0
E0910 10:34:05.286323933   26069 sync_posix.cc:47]           assertion failed: pthread_mutex_lock(mu) == 0
E0910 10:34:05.310868135   26075 sync_posix.cc:47]           assertion failed: pthread_mutex_lock(mu) == 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Your workers might be running out of memory.

Run `dmesg` and look for any "out of memory" errors.